# Moving rows to another sheet google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi guy's i'm trying to create a to-do list at google sheets and i'm using a template from google

and i found a script at youtube to clear the done tasks and it's working.

But, i need to do one more thing, i need to move the completed tasks to another sheet and i tried so many scripts and i can't get it to work.

My main sheet is "Tarefas" and the completed sheet is "Finalizadas"

my sheet is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DZgXfHoQ3hwbBCPpLAOoQ8Jd0u5OMeQpX_OWWlgpa2I/edit?usp=sharing

and the code to clear the rows is:

```
    function ClearRecords()
{
  // DECLARE ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // DECLARE SHEET
  var todoSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tarefas");
  
  // LAST ROW ON TO DO SHEET
  var lastRowToDo = todoSheet.getLastRow();
  
  // GET LAST TASK
  for(var x = 4; x <= lastRowToDo; x++)
  {
    if(todoSheet.getRange(x,3).isBlank() == true)
    {
       var lastTaskRow = x - 1;
      
    }          
  }

  for(var i = 4; i <= lastTaskRow; i++)
  {
    if(todoSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == true)
    {
       todoSheet.getRange("B" + i + ":C" + i).setValues([["",""]]);
       todoSheet.getRange(i, 1).setValue(false);

    }       
  }
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var OpenRows = [];
  
  for(var i = 4; i <= lastTaskRow; i++)
  {
    if(todoSheet.getRange(i,3).isBlank() == true)
    {
       OpenRows.push(i); 
    }
    else
    {
       if(OpenRows.length > 0)
       {
         var nextRow = OpenRows.shift();
         var values = todoSheet.getRange("B" + i + ":C" + i).getValues();
         todoSheet.getRange("B" + nextRow  + ":C" + nextRow).setValues(values);
         todoSheet.getRange("B" + i + ":C" + i).setValues([["",""]]);
         OpenRows.push(i); 

       }  
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can I ask you about the detail of `i can't get it to work.`? 2. When I saw your `Finalizadas`, it seems that the sheet is empty. In order to correctly understand about `i need to move the completed tasks to another sheet`, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I need to when i put the script to work it move the tasks that i set to done to sheets finalizadas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on there in that script, but this can probably be done more easily by checking what rows have a checkbox checked, which indicates that a task is done. Then you move that row to the second sheet.

The last function in the spreadsheet you shared (`teste()`) is closer to this idea than the one you pasted here, so I made some changes to it:

```
function moveDoneTasks() {
  // DECLARE ACTIVE SPREADSHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // DECLARE SHEETS
  var todoSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tarefas");
  var doneSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Finalizadas");

  // Not used
  //  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  //  var sheetNameToWatch = ss.getSheetByName("Tarefas")
  //  var columnNumberToWatch = 8;
  //  var valueToWatch = "DONE" ;
  //  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Finalizadas";
  //  var range = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  // LAST ROW ON TO DO SHEET
  // var lastRowToDo = todoSheet.getLastRow(); // This would get all rows of the sheet, not just the non-empty ones
  // Get non-empty rows in C column (Tarefa) - Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637159/3751868
  var lastRowToDo = ss.getRange("C1:C").getValues().filter(String).length+1;  
  
  // MOVE TASKS WITH CHECKBOX CHECKED (✓)
  for(var x = 4; x <= lastRowToDo; x++){
    var rowCheckboxCell = todoSheet.getRange(x, 1, 1, 1);
    if(rowCheckboxCell.isChecked()) { // See if the checkbox in the first column of the row is checked
      // var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Finalizadas"); // It is not necessary to do this inside the loop, since it doesn't change
      var targetRange = doneSheet.getRange(doneSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      // ss.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange); // This is getting the range in the spreadsheet, not the Finalizadas sheet
      todoSheet.getRange(x, 2, 1, todoSheet.getLastColumn()-1).moveTo(targetRange);      
      // sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow()); // It is not necessary to delete the row because the moveTo() function already removes it from the original sheet
      rowCheckboxCell.uncheck(); // Uncheck moved tasks
    }
  } 
}
```

To make it easier to use, I'd suggest adding a menu to the spreadsheet to call the function:

```
function onOpen(){
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 .createMenu('Avançado')
 .addItem('Mover tarefas finalizadas', 'moveDoneTasks')
 .addToUi();
}
```